# Disabling select field before xhr not working

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have the code:

```
    loadFieldOptions: function(field) {
        field.innerHTML = '<option selected>Loading...</option>';
        field.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');

        ...

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', url, false);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (XMLHttpRequest.DONE == xhr.readyState) {
                if (200 == xhr.status) {

                    // update field with new data
                    field.innerHTML = data;
                    field.removeAttribute('disabled');

                }
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    },
```

But field not disable. I guess it's because xhr blocking thread before fields disabled. How to fix it? Using open in main thread is mandatory. Thanx

Comment: What is `field` actually?

Comment: @goto1 field is a select tag

Answer (score 0):

try to change this `xhr.open('POST', url, false);` by this `xhr.open('POST', url, true);` because when you set the third option of `XHR.open()` to false it means that `XHR.send()` will wait until it have a response to return something but if you set it to true wich is the default value it not wait that means that you can do other tasks while `XHR.send()` is running.

Comment: "executed in the main thread but if you set it to true wich is the default value it will run in the background" - this is incorrect, it's still running on the main thread, but it's asynchronous so it can do other things while the XHR call is waiting to complete

Comment: you are totally right its just that I don't have his full project so this idea popped into my mind, I just miss explained that, thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanx for answering but the main problem that I need to use exactly false parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are properly checking the `statusCode` of your response. Typically with `POST` requests, you get a `201`, which indicates that

> the request has been fulfilled and has resulted in one or more new resources being created.

Here's a working example that mimics what you're trying to do:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("fetch-options");

btn.addEventListener("click", fetchAndRenderOptions);

function fetchAndRenderOptions() {
  const field = document.querySelector("select");

  field.innerHTML = "<option selected>Loading...</option>";
  field.setAttribute("disabled", true);

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("POST", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 201) {
      const result = JSON.parse(this.response);
      field.innerHTML = `
        <option value="${result.foo}" selected>${result.foo}</option>
        <option value="${result.lorem}">${result.lorem}</option>
        <option value="${result.id}">${result.id}</option>
      `;
      field.removeAttribute("disabled");
      return;
    }
  };
  xhr.send("foo=bar&lorem=ipsum");
}
```

```html
<button id="fetch-options" type="button">Fetch options</button>
<hr />
<select></select>
```

Comment: But my server return 200 response. So nothing changes for me

Comment: @OleksiiZamaldinov as you can see from the example above, which you can run and test it yourself, this works, so unless you're missing something, it should work for you as well.